# Excel row comparison to columns functions/vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Problem: I have data that looks like this and I want to compare the rows to the column values.
so is(Table1.t1 = Table2.t1)? kind of thing.

```
Table 1
A B
x t1
x t2
x t3
x t4

Table 2

A B  C  D  E
x t1 t2 t3 t4
```

Can I do this in Excel with functions or VBA

Comment: I've done a bit a research on this and because of some weaknesses in VBA there isn't a concise and efficient way to do this.  In VBA you'll have to compare each cell at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in A1:B8, you have

```
x   t1
x   t2
x   t3
x   t4
y   u1
y   u2
y   u3
y   u4
```

and in A11:E12, you have

```
x   t1  t2  t3  t4
y   u1  u2  u3  u4
```

then put this formula in C1 and fill down

```
=B1=OFFSET(INDEX($A$11:$A$12,MATCH(A1,$A$11:$A$12,FALSE),1),0,COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1),1,1)
```

It will return TRUE if the data matches, and FALSE if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question, there are a few ideas that might lead you in the right direction:

- If you just want to "flip" the data in one of the two tables so you can compare the tables directly, just do a `Copy`, `Paste Special`, and check the "Transpose" button. If you want to do this with VBA, just record it as a macro and see what it records.
- If you want to use VBA, I think that using `Cells(row#,col#)` instead of `Range()` is the key.

So lets assume your two tables are in B10:B20 (vertical) and C2:L2 (horizontal). The loop to compare them might look something like:

```
Sub CompareFlippedTables
    Dim i as integer
    For i = 1 to 10
        If Cells(i + 10,2).Value = Cells(2, i + 3).Value Then
           'Do something useful'
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes you understand my question perfectly Brad and in fact you answered it correctly for the most part but I was not clear as for the end result. So ultimately, I wan to do a vlookup where I have one column t1 t2 t3 t4 and another column with the same data (in theory) but from a different source. By comparing the 2 columns I can then confirm the data from 2 different sources is the same. Transpose does not give me 1 column for all rows, rather 1 column for each row. I would like 1 column for all rows so i can compare them to the other column of data. Thanks!